# How to query data from Firebase Realtime DB if the key has multiple words?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have something like this in my DB where some keys like "Class Units" consists of two or more words.

[image]

What I'm trying to do is to read the data and print it to my console, but im having trouble reading the values from these multiple-word keys.

```
  database.ref('7290').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
  var course = snapshot.val();
  console.log(course.Career);
  });
```

I was able to print the value for `Career` because it's only one word.

Is there anything I can do to get the value for keys that are two words since I can't call `course.Class Units`?

Can anyone help please?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So javascript provides you a couple ways to get to object properties: dot notation (`course.Career`) or brackets (`course["Career"]`).

Using the second, we can have keys that are non-standard, as you are getting. Here's a sample (note I'm just creating an object and using that, rather than fetching from FireBase, but the principle is the same):

```js
let course = {
  "id": 7290,
  "Career": "UGRD",
  "Catalog": 402,
  "Class Units": 3,
  "Component Code": "LEC",
  "Component Descr": "Lecture",
  "Course ID": "031564",
  "Equivalent Courses": "SOCI 402",
  "Long Title": "CONTEMPORARY SOCIOLOGY",
  "Pre Requisite Description": "Prereq: SoCI 302",
  "Subject": "SOCI"
};

/**
 * The first option below uses dot notation, as you have
 *   used in your current code.
 **/
console.log("Dot notation, Career: "+course.Career);

/**
 * The second one uses brackets to get to the object key.
 *   doing this, we can have names that are more non-standard.
 **/
console.info("Brackets, Class Units: "+course['Class Units'])
```